# How to get GCC/Clang to error on reserved identifiers

Tags: c++, linter

In large codebases, it might be impossible for the maintainer/project-owner to review and audit every line of code. In C++, some identifiers are reserved (according to the standard) and prohibiting the definition of reserved identifiers seems reasonable.

According to [Identifiers - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers):

> - the identifiers with a double underscore anywhere are reserved;
> - the identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved;
> - the identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace.

---

Is there tooling to enforce this guideline (prohibit the use of reserved identifiers)?

For instance, is it possible (through GCC, Clang, clang-tidy, or some other compiler or linter) to get code like the following snippet to error:

```cpp
auto __destination = cv::Mat3f(1, 1);
cv::cvtColor(source, __destination, cv::ColorConversionCodes::COLOR_HSV2RGB);
auto result = __destination.at<cv::Vec3f>(0, 0);
```

I know I can either hack around this by testing some regular expressions against the codebase or even solve it decently by parsing the C++ code into a parse tree and then validating all identifiers, but I am interested in knowing whether or not there is already something that does this.

I would be interested in forbidding even the use of already defined variables starting with a double underscore as it could be a hack exploiting a [GCC leaky abstraction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9_mYmvO4Ow), for instance.

Comment: `clang -Weverything` doesn't warn about it, so I guess that's a no for clang.

Comment: clang-tidy includes a decent way to implement additional custom checks, but it requires compiling a new clang-tidy executable.

Answer (score 4):

Clang has this feature starting from version 13 with `-Wreserved-identifier` flag ([link](https://reviews.llvm.org/D93095?id=314329)).

GCC doesn't implement such feature yet (as in March 2022).